# Limit jQuery slider to the value of another slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I was working on a situation when I had two jQuery slider controls that I took from here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin

I needed to restrict one based on the value of another so that they didn't overlap. I came up with the code below. It worked, except one very annoying issue - when I was dragging the sliders they would go past one another while I was still dragging them, only to restore to the restricted value upon me releasing the mouse button.

Purely by accident I found a solution of adding the ui.someunknownmethod('1'); line below.

So my question is, can I keep that line without causing any issues?

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}

    #slider1 .ui-slider-range { background: #8ae234; }
    #slider2 .ui-slider-range { background: #729fcf; }

    #sliderContainer{
        width: 400px;
        margin: 6px 0px;
    }


</style>    
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Slider -->
        <div id="sliderContainer">
        <div id="slider1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="sliderContainer">
        <div id="slider2"></div>
        </div>

        <span id="txt">-</span>
        <span id="txt2">-</span>

    <script>
    $(function(){
        $("#slider1").slider({
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: "max",
            max: 255,
            value: 50,
            slide: refresh1,
            change: refresh1
        });
        $("#slider2").slider({
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: "max",
            max: 255,
            value: 30,
            slide: refresh2,
            change: refresh2
        });
    });

    function refresh1(e, ui)
    {
        var slider2 = $("#slider2");

        var v1 = ui.value;
        var v2 = slider2.slider('value');

        if(v1 < v2)
        {
            $("#slider1").slider('value', v2);

            //This is the line that "saves the day"
            ui.someunknownmethod('1');
        }

        $("#txt").text(v1);
    }
    function refresh2(e, ui)
    {
        var slider1 = $("#slider1");

        var v1 = slider1.slider('value');
        var v2 = ui.value;

        if(v2 > v1)
        {
            $("#slider2").slider('value', v1);

            //This is the line that "saves the day"
            ui.someunknownmethod('1');
        }

        $("#txt2").text(v2);
    }

    </script>
    </body>
```

**EDIT:** Don't use the approach of throwing an unhandled exception -- it will work in most browsers, of course, except older IE's where a browser would show a message box pop-up for each error encountered. That would be quite annoying for a user!

So far I was not able to find what I'm looking for, (well apart from rewriting a slider UI code) so if anyone finds it out, please post it here...

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like

```
$("#slider2").slider("option", "min", 25);
```

or

```
$("#slider2").slider("option", "max", 25);
```

see http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#methods for more information/methods

Comment: It won't restrict the position of the slider. It will simply set its minimum range value but the slider head can still physically be dragged to the very left/right side of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [the API](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-max), it seems you can change "min" and "max" also after the slider has been already initialized. All you need to do is to keep slider1 "min" option equal to slider2 "max" option, updating whenever one of them has been dragged.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents (main `slider` will update sub `slider`'s `min value`:

```
jQuery(function($){

    var handle1 = $( "#sub" );
    $( "#sub-slider" ).slider({
        min: 12,
        max: 28,
        create: function() {
            handle1.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
        },
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            handle1.text( ui.value );
        }
    });

    //#menu-line

    var handle = $( "#main" );
    var main_val;
    $( "#main-slider" ).slider({
        min: 16,
        max: 36,
        create: function() {
            handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
        },
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            handle.text( ui.value );
            main_val = ui.value;
            $( "#sub" ).text(main_val);
            $( "#sub-slider" ).slider( 'option', 'min', main_val);
        }
    });

});
```